# Can I replace Pentium 2117u with Core i7 3537U on my Asus x550c laptop?

Tags: laptop, cpu, upgrade

Can I replace the Intel Pentium 2117u CPU with Intel Core i7 3537U on my Asus x550c laptop?

Answer (score 0):

Your CPU From: [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumer_Ultra-Low_Voltage)

[image]

New CPU From: [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Core_i7_microprocessors)

[image]

They are the same socket, so it looks like it should be ok, as far as power goes, not really sure.

Comment: They're both 17W. It will come down to whether the BIOS and chipset can support it.